# import from github repository into Python jupyter notebook

Tags: python-3.x, git, jupyter-notebook, conda

**Goal:** I want to import this library https://github.com/Kaggle/learntools into a jupyternotebook so that I can use use both the following packages:

```
from learntools.core import binder
from learntools.machine_learning.ex8 import *
```

To do this, I tried to two methods to clone the github library with this command.

1st method:

```
conda install git 
pip install auto-py-to-exe
pip install git+https://github.com/Kaggle/learntools.git
```

2nd method:

```
%%bash
git clone https://github.com/Kaggle/learntools
```

**Situation/Problem:**

1st method gave this error:

```
WARNING: Discarding git+https://github.com/Kaggle/learntools.git. Command errored out with exit status 1: python setup.py egg_info Check the logs for full command output.
ERROR: Command errored out with exit status 1: python setup.py egg_info Check the logs for full command output.
```

2nd method gave this error:
`bash: line 1: git: command not found`

Question: How can I clone/import this github library https://github.com/Kaggle/learntools into my jupyter notebook so that I can use its packages in the code.

Thank you for taking your time in answering it.

Seems like a really basic step to do, but somehow is not working on my side.

Answer (score 0):

#### First method

Can't really do much for you since you haven't provided the full log output.

#### Second method

It looks like you've installed git in your conda environment, but not to your machine as a whole. I believe the instance of bash that is being used for your second method is not using your conda environment. You didn't share your conda environment's name, but if we assume it's `gitenv`, You could try this:

```
conda activate gitenv && git clone https://github.com/Kaggle/learntools
```

However, I'd recommend that you simply install git for your whole machine. I can't think of any reason to have it installed only in a conda environment.

Once you have the repo cloned, you'll have to use pip to install it as a package.